# App Script Google - No muestra activador

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

He creado un formulario con Google Forms, quisiera crearme un algoritmo en App Script de google, que me permita, de acuerdo a una respuesta enviar los datos a diferentes hojas, sin embargo iniciando la funcion, quiero hacer pruebas y no me aparece la opción en los activadores, para ejecutar "De un formulario -- Al enviarse el formulario".

He buscado información de varios foros, la mayoría tienen como crear un formulario desde código, sin embargo no logro encontrar que ha pasado con ese activador / Trigger / Disparador, solo me muestra dos y es segun tiempo o segun calendario.

¿Es posible que a la fecha actual Google haya desactivado este disparador?, si es así, como puedo capturar la información al enviar el formulario, ya el dividir la información para varios destinos puedo hacerlo, lo que quisiera lograr es que el algoritmo se ejecute al enviarse el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te aparece la opción de crear una activador desde formulario entonces es que estás en un proyecto "standalone" en lugar de están en un proyecto "bounded".

Podrías crear un proyecto "bounded" a tu formulario o a una hoja de cálculo vinculada a tu formulario o bien en lugar de crear el activador usando la interfaz de usuario de Google Apps Script lo hagas mediante código. Para esto necesitarás un objeto de tu formulario o de hoja de cálculo.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
.forSpreadsheet(SpredsheetApp.openById('pon_aqui_el_id_de_tu_spreadsheet'))
.onFormSubmit()
.create()
```